# SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for D:\xampp\tmp\php83FA.tmp

Tags: laravel-6

When sumbit thoes field, it store my public path but face this

> error:SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for D:\xampp\tmp\php83FA.tmp
>   in laravel

Comment: i am also looking for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 6 use this code for file upload

```
  if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
      $path = $files->store('uploads/feedback');
  }

  $feedbackData = Feedback::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'image' => $path,
    'state_country' => $request->state_country,
    'feedback' => $request->feedback,
    'status' => $request->status,
  ]);
```

Comment: Some information on how this code works would be helpful.

Comment: Once upload the image store as storage public folder, after you run the below command

php artisan storage:link